# VB 2010 Form Show

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio

i currently have multiple forms (around 30 forms) and i am switching between forms. The Main form (Form1) has 29 buttons and each button will take me to the respective form number (example: button3 = form3, button20=form20, etc).

I understand that I can use the code:

```
me.hide
form1.show
```

I want a method to pass the form name dynamically, something along the lines of:

```
me.controls(FormName).show
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project with three forms (Form1, Form2, and Form3). Put two buttons on Form1 (named Button2 and Button3), then place the following source code in Form1:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Call FormFromButton(DirectCast(sender, Button))
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Call FormFromButton(DirectCast(sender, Button))
  End Sub

  Public Sub FormFromButton(btn As Button)
    Dim i As Integer = CInt(btn.Name.Substring(6)) 'Get number after "button" (6 characters)
    Dim f As Form = GetForm("Form" & i.ToString)
    f.Show()
    f.Activate()
  End Sub

  Public Function GetForm(formClassName As String) As Form
    'see if it is already instanced
    For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
      If f.GetType.Name = formClassName Then Return f
    Next f
    'create new instance
    Dim strFullName As String = Me.GetType.Namespace & "." & formClassName
    Dim o As Object = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(strFullName)
    Dim frm As Form = DirectCast(o, Form)
    Return frm
  End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Myself created 4 forms one is parent another 3(Form3,Form4,Form5) is child  and i was created 3 buttons in parent form and that button Text is Form3,Form4,Form5

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
                Dim btn As Button
                btn = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)
                AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.buttonclick
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub buttonclick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim frmname As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Dim frmAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.ExecutablePath)
        For Each type As Type In frmAssembly.GetTypes
            If type.BaseType = GetType(Form) Then
                If (type.Name = frmname.Text) Then
                    Dim frmshow As Form = DirectCast(frmAssembly.CreateInstance(type.ToString()), Form)
                    For Each frm As Form In Me.MdiChildren
                        frm.Close()
                    Next
                    frmshow.Show()
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim formname As String = "form" & btn.Name(btn.Name.Length - 1)
    Dim frm As Form = GetForm(formname)
    frm.Show()
End Sub
Private Function GetForm(ByVal Formname As String) As Form
    Dim t As Type = Type.GetType(Formname) ', True, True)
    If t Is Nothing Then
        Dim Fullname As String = Application.ProductName & "." & Formname
        t = Type.GetType(Fullname, True, True)
    End If
    Return CType(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)
End Function
Private Sub AddHandlers()
    AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
    AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
    AddHandler Button3.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
    AddHandler Button4.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
End Sub
Private Sub RemoveHandlers()
    RemoveHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
    RemoveHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
    RemoveHandler Button3.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
    RemoveHandler Button4.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
End Sub
Private Sub Form2_Activated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    AddHandlers()
End Sub
Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    RemoveHandlers()
End Sub
```